# Dictionaries/libraries Usage

Tags: discord.py

I'm still new to coding with python and coding  in general, so i dont know what libraries/dictionaries are or what they are used for specifically. I would appreciate any document links and ideas for me to get started on it.
If i can i want to use it for a lock and unlock command system, i know it works because i has someone else to use it, i just need to know how to create one

[link to the lock and unlock commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76597459/voice-channel-locking-and-unlocking)
Im linking this so anyone who can help can have a reference as to what im working on and what im looking for

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Comment: This is honestly way too big/fundamental a question for SO. I'd suggest having a look at some online tutorials and trying some stuff out on your own first, and coming back when you have a more specific issue. A good place to start might be the [W3 tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), in particular those about [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) and [modules](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp) (also called libraries), if you're unsure what these are.

Answer (score 1):

Python Libraries are a set of useful functions that eliminate the need for writing codes from scratch, almost like code that you download from the internet, for instance the discord.py library is `support` for writing discord bots in python.

If you are new to python then I wouldn't suggest learning discord.py until you have a fair grasp on the language, however if you want to make a lock command then you can use the `channel.set_permissions` method to set the channel permissions so the `@everyone` role cant type, to create a command it would look something like this.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel: ctx.channel):
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, add_reactions=False, create_public_threads=False)
    await ctx.send(f'Channel locked\n{reason}')
```

To try to and learn discord.py then you are probably better of [reading the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).